# What does Dart "Error: Can't return a value from a void function." mean?

Tags: function, dart, return, void

I can't understand what void function in Dart means. Below is an example where output from `map` method can't be returned. I'm new to Dart and would appreciate simplified explanation.

```
void main() {
  var myList = [1, 2, 3];
  var output = myList.map((i) => i * 2);
  return output;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> `void` A special type that indicates a value that’s never used. Functions like printInteger() and main() that don’t explicitly return a value have the void return type. For more information, see this [article](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-legacy-of-the-void-e7afb5f44df0).

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#a-basic-dart-program

In short, it is a type you use to indicate that your method does not return any (usable) value. For `main` method, you cannot return any value. You can instead e.g. print the result using `print` like:

```
void main() {
  var myList = [1, 2, 3];
  var output = myList.map((i) => i * 2);
  print(output); // (2, 4, 6)
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I just realised that I was solving CodeWars problem in DartPad and forgot about it. Silly me :)